# Letters y,g,f are not displayed properly with dotted border in html

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Letter y,g,f are not displayed properly when it is the first letter in the word.
[image: Letter y in yellow is not displayed properly in first word alone]

```
<style>
.fillin{
   min-width:15%;
  border:none;
  border-bottom:2px dotted black;
  outline:none;
  font-style:italic; font-weight: 600;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  height: 17px;
  margin: 0;
  padding:20px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  space: 0;
}
</style>
<span style="display:inline-block"> <input spellcheck="false" class="fillin" type="text" /> </span>
```

Comment: this is due to you input is going overflowing outside the container

Comment: Give a little padding or text-indent, so the italic font is not drawn outside ils container.